# Best practices for returning representation of resource that is also a collection

Tags: rest, get, webdav

Let's say I want to make a RESTful interface, and I want to work with `foo`s based upon their IDs. Nothing new here:

- `GET /api/foo1` returns a representation (e.g. using JSON) of `foo1`.
- `DELETE /api/foo1` deletes `foo1`.

etc.

Now let me tell you that a "foo" is a collection type thing. So I want to be able to add a "bar" to a "foo":

- `PUT /api/foo1/bar3` adds `bar3` to `foo1`.
- `GET /api/foo1/bar3` returns a representation of `foo1`.
- `DELETE /api/foo1/bar3` removes `bar3` from `foo1`.
- `DELETE /api/foo1` deletes `foo1` altogether.

Now the question remains: what does `GET /api/foo1` do? Does it it simply return a representation of `foo1` as I originally assumed in this question? Or does it return a list of bars? Or does it return a representation of `foo1` that is both a description of `foo1` as well as *includes* a list of all contained bars?

Or should `GET /api/foo1` merely return a representation of `foo1` as I assumed at the beginning, and require a `PROPFIND` request to list the bars inside `foo1` (the approach taken by WebDAV)? But then in order to be consistent, wouldn't I have to change all my other list-type functionality to `PROPFIND`, directly contradicting all those thousands of RESTful tutorials that say to use `GET /api/foo1` to list the contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some pondering, I think the best conceptual explanation from a RESTful perspective is that usually the "thing" is not the same thing as its "collection". So while in the WebDAV world a `directory/` might be the same thing that holds its files, in the RESTful world I might have a separate `directory/files/` subpath for the contained files. That way I can manipulate directories separately from the files that hold.

Consider a RESTful API for a farm which contains barns. The endpoint `farm/api/barns/` might return a list of barns, one of which would be `farm/api/barns/bigredbarn`. Naively I would think that retrieving `farm/api/barns/bigredbarn/` would provide me a list of animals in the barn, which is what prompted this question.

But really the animals in the barn is only one aspect of the Big Red Barn. It might contain vehicles and hay:

- `farm/api/barns/bigredbarn/animals/`
- `farm/api/barns/bigredbarn/vehicles/`
- `farm/api/barns/bigredbarn/haybales/`

With this approach the dilemma I faced does not arise.

Comment: I like your approach. In fact, it is the same behavior that truly object oriented languages implement for array or list objects:

Array object properties: Length, Dimensions, ReadOnly

Array method GetValue  - returns an item

List object properties: Head, Current

List method GetEnumerator - returns an object that in turn will return items

Answer (score 2):

The semantics of webdav has never really been reconciled with the idioms of RESTful interfaces.

In theory, GET should retrieve a representation of a state of a resource and PROPFIND should be used to retrieve the members of a collection.

So you should do this:

- GET /api/foo1/ - returns state of foo1 only
- PROPFIND /api/foo1/ - returns the members of foo1

Most front end devs would freak out if you told them to use PROPFIND, although its completely supported in browser js implementations.

Personally i use a webdav/json gateway, where requests are made using RESTful idioms, but routed to my webdav implementation

For example i would do this:

```
GET /api/foo1/_PROPFIND?fields=name,fooProp1,fooProp2
```

And that would return

```
[
{ name : "bar1", fooProp1: "..", fooProp2 : ".."},
{ name : "bar2", fooProp1: "..", fooProp2 : ".."}
]
```

One advantage of this approach is that client's get to control the json properties returned. This is good because a rich API will have a lot of properties, but in most situations clients dont need all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The routes and their operations in RESTfull API are completely designed by the developers. It's the developer who decides what to return while requesting a specific route say, `GET /api/foo1`.

And the developer should design every route including  `/api/foo1/bar`. There is no specific rule on what a particular route should do. If your API is an open-source project make a clean and clear documentation of every route.

Don't waste your time thinking about the old school strategies.